# flower cannot monitor custom queue

Tags: celery, flower

After setting up celery, Redis and flower I made some basic tests, everything worked fine using the default `celery` queue. After that I created some custom queues and then flower couldn't monitor these custom queues. I think flower continues to monitor `celery` queue. Although, flower can monitor the results properly.

celery project report:

```
software -> celery:4.2.1 (windowlicker) kombu:4.2.1 py:2.7.15rc1
            billiard:3.5.0.4 redis:2.10.6
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:redis results:redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0

broker_url: u'redis://url/0'
result_backend: u'redis://url/0'
task_routes: {
    u'celery.crawler.fbk.download_alt_text': {   u'queue': u'fbk_alt_text'}}
```

flower command:

```
celery flower -A downloader -Q fbk_alt_text --broker=redis://url:6379/0
```

proof of concept:
[image: flower_monitor]
[image: flower_broker]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Celery worker and flower are not configured correctly as per the screenshots. Ensure celery worker is consuming the tasks from that queue.

If celery worker is consuming a queue then flower will show queues in broker section.

```
celery worker -l info -A app -Q foo
flower -A app -Q foo
```

In broker section, it should show `foo`.

[image]